# Email notification if change task past due date on Service Now

Tags: javascript, email-notifications, servicenow

I am trying to set up an email notification ONLY IF a change task is past due date! The email should only be sent to the person who has been assigned the change task.

This is what I am doing :

1)This is the script in the scheduled job :

```
      var gr = new GlideRecord('change_task');
      gr.addQuery('due_date','<=', gs.nowDateTime());
      gr.query();


      var count = gr.getRowCount();
      if (count > 0)
      {
        gs.eventQueue("change_task.duedate_reminder", gr, gs.getUserID(), gs.userName());
      }
```

2) Created an event in registry named "change_task.duedate_reminder "

3) Created an email notification when the above mentioned event is fired. Used 'aasigned_to' as the recipient!!

This is the error log message:

"getEventTarget() called with invalid record reference.change_task. for event: change_task.duedate_reminder, could have been deleted"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if `count` is greater than 0, you need to call `gr.next()` to load each record in the collection, otherwise, the `gr` instance you are passing to `gs.eventQueue(...)` is going to be unpopulated with results (eventQueue only handles a single, populated GlideRecord).

If you're potentially expecting a collection of records, you'll need to iterate them like so:

```
gr.query();
while (gr.next()){
   gs.eventQueue("change_task.duedate_reminder", gr, gs.getUserID(), gs.userName());
}
```

Comment: I'd also add that the current script would end up sending a notification to every single past-due change task every time it's run.
If you're wanting it only to send the notification *one time*, you'll need to change your query up a bit to only grab items since the last run of the script.

For example, if the script runs once an hour:

var gr = new GlideRecord('change_task');
gr.addQuery('due_date','<=', gs.nowDateTime());
gr.addQuery('due_date','>', gs.hoursAgo(1));
gr.query();